# Upgrading my Graphics card. Is it compatible with my current build?

Tags: graphics-card, computer-building

I've decided upgrading my graphics card seems way overdue but I'm not very clued up as to what makes a graphics card compatible or not.

My current specs:

- Intel i5-2400 - 3.1Ghz
- Motherboard - Foxconn N15235 (Not sure if this is right, it's what I found on the board)
- nVidia GTX 560 (Removing it for the new one)
- Corsair CX600
- 4x2GB RAM
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

New Card - nVidia GTX 960

From what I've read the Bus support should be compatible (from PCI-E 2.0 x16 to PCI Express 3.0 x16)

Power supply wise, the new card has a minimum of 500W and the old card requires 450W so would my 600W psu still have enough overhead or would more be recommended? The new card seems to need 1 less 6-pin connector as well so I guess that's good?

Would there be anything else I would need to ensure the new graphics card would be compatible?

Sorry if this is a bad question but I really lack knowledge when it comes to PC components and I want to be sure before a commit to buying anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what makes a graphics card compatible or not.

If it fits in the slot it's compatible.

> Power supply wise, the new card has a minimum of 500W and the old card requires 450W so would my 600W psu still have enough overhead or would more be recommended?

Your new card uses around 100w. A 300W PSU would be recommended, anything higher will be wasteful and inefficient.

Comment: What's the difference between the 'max usage' and 'minimum psu requirement' I see on the specs for the graphics card then? I just assumed allowing for the bigger number (even if it wasn't the max?) was a safe bet.

Comment: I don't see either of those numbers on the specifications. The specifications say: Graphics Card Power (W)
120 W

Minimum Recommended 
System Power (W)
400 W. PSU recommendations are pretty much always bloated and exaggerated, nomatter where you look.

Comment: I was looking at the novatech specs. I guess they replace recommended with minimum. I'll check the length then. seems like the new one is just over an inch longer

Comment: Ah. I was looking at the ones from nvidia.com. Yes, size can be an issue depending on your case dimensions, though most normal size cases should have standard dimensions and so do most cards.